# trouble deploying spinnaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker

so i have tried deploying spinnaker in AWS in a few different ways, but always get the same problem.

Just after installing using the AWS quick start, I try to create an application and I get this error:

```
Could not create application: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
```

so i check http://localhost:8080/health and get no response. As far as I can tell front50 isnt running (it isn't in the process list when i run 'top')

```
checking /var/log/upstart/front50.log i get this:
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.Main.main(Main.groovy:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:384)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:156)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
        ... 10 more
```

NOTE: i am pretty new to linux and spinnaker so I am likely missing something obvious. however I just ran the AWS quick start and I expected that to just work.

Also, at the moment I am just wanting to try it out, so if anyone knows of anywhere I can just give it a test without much hassel. That would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to try it out I'd recommend one of these solutions:
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/quickstart/

Otherwise you should give halyard a go - it's a tool specifically designed to help configure, verify, and deploy spinnaker.

Answer (score 0):

If the deployment is failing at the healthcheck, update the readiness probe of each deployment to point to the tcpSocket.

```
readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 1
  tcpSocket:
    port: 8080
  timeoutSeconds: 1
```